# How to efficiently render and process the content in a GapBuffer?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have learned about GapBuffer lately, and tried to implement one as a backend of an editor. However, after completing the basic functions of GapBuffer, I could not figure out how to render the GapBuffer efficiently.

If I render the GapBuffer by iterating through every character not in the gap, it will be an *O(n)* operation (*n* being the number of chars). But the purpose of a GapBuffer is to reduce the amortized complexity of inserting and removing chars near the cursor, to be almost *O(1)*. If each insertion/deletion triggers the rendering, it will be *O(n)* anyway.

And if there is linting or colorization, that will take at least *O(n)* as well.

Is there any trick to do accomplish the rendering from GapBuffer faster? Or is *O(n)* the best performance of insertion/deletion in a full editor?

---

I am using C#, and trying to render the GapBuffer to a GUI front end. But if there are tricks to do this on a terminal font end, that would be great to learn about as well.

Comment: You only have to render a screenful of text at the most